# How do I get submitted form value in React?

Tags: forms, reactjs

Here is my React Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import categories from './categories.json'
import './content.css'

export default class Content extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            searchText: '',
            categories
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="content">
            <form className="searchform" onSubmit={this.search}>
                <input type="text" name="keyword" id="searchbox" placeholder="Search String"></input>
                <select name="categories" id="searchcategories">
                <option defaultValue="" defaultChecked>Select a category</option>
                {this.state.categories.map(x => 
                    <option key={x.value} value={x.value}>{x.name}</option>
                )}</select>
                <input type="submit" value ="Search" id="searchsubmit" />
            </form>
            </div>
        )
    }

    search(e) {
        console.log(e.target)
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

On clicking the submit button, my function `search` does get called. However, how do I get the submitted values?

`e.target` gives me the whole form DOM HTML
`e.target.value` is `undefined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In React, you have two options for form components:

*Controlled components* (https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) have their value linked to component state by setting their value prop to a state variable.  In this scenario, you can use your component's this.state to inspect their values.

*Uncontrolled components* (https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) can have references attached to their parent component when instantiated... typically like this `ref={(input) => this.input = input}`.  When your function `search` is called, you can inspect the reference for the value, i.e. `this.input.value`.

Comment: I see. Which one is better to use this react though, considering performance and efficiency?

Comment: Controlled components should be generally used. Use uncontrolled components only when it's really required, its generally avoided

Comment: Thanks! Controlled Components worked, and those links are great!

Comment: Question, do I need to create a different handleChange for all my form elements?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the state variables for this. 
For example sync this.state.searchText with the  element whenever text changes. And then define a callback mechanism like -

```
onSubmit={()=>{
console.log('My searchBox's latest value is : ',this.state.searchText);
}}
```

Remember, in React we follow a unidirectional flow. So, we always take our data from props or states, and do not need to work on DOM traversals.

Comment: I added `value={this.state.searchText}` to my `input#searchbox`, but now I can't type in the text box

Comment: Use <input type="text" name="keyword" onchange=(text)={this.setState(<whatever state variable you need to set>)} placeholder="Search String"></input>