# How to access the selected option in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React JSX, I wrote below component:

```
<select //...
  onChange={event => {alert(event.target); //setState}}
>
    <option id=1>one</option>
    <option id=2>two</option>
</select>
```

The alert gives me select element. How can I access selected option without jQuery? I am trying to setState on the id, and do corresponding searches and other things.

Comment: use `value` instead of `id` in your option tags. And then you can access it by: `event.target.value`.

Comment: How is this problem specific to React?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of an `id` on `select` option, provide the `value` attribute you can then access it as `event.target.value`.

```
<select 
    onChange={event => {
        alert(event.target.value);
    }
}>
    <option value="1"> one</option>
    <option value="2"> two</option>
</select>
```

**[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j4l80mz35)**

Comment: because on select of input the value attribute on select is set to the value of the select option, which is the behaviour of select element

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn’t typically access the value directly through the event target.  Either bind the control value to component state or store a reference on the parent component... then you can access the value when the event is fired.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47842562/1306026

Comment: Thanks Josh. But this is about manipulating Search component itself, so no dependency with Result or Wrapper. Selected answer worked for me. `onChange` only changes the `state` variable, which is used in `render`.

Answer (score 1):

You can access selected option like:

```
var elm = event.target;
console.log(elm.options[elm.selectedIndex]);
```

and then access its value or text like:

```
console.log(elm.options[elm.selectedIndex].value)
```

DEMO (*change the option to see result*):

```js
function setState() {
  var elm = event.target;
  console.log(elm.options[elm.selectedIndex]);
  console.log(elm.options[elm.selectedIndex].value);
}
```

```html
<select onChange="setState()">
    <option id=1>one</option>
    <option id=2>two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Good level of detail Palash. I am sorry I cant accept this as answer since first answer of Shubham solved issue.

Comment: No problem. I am more than happy if it helped you or future users in any way.